# Why is my Angular App slower on Azure App Service Linux than on App Service Windows

Tags: .net, angular, linux, visual-studio, azure-web-app-service

I have an Angular App that uses .NET 6 WebAPIs. I created the application using the Visual Studio 2022 template "ASP.NET Core with Angular". The application calls an SQL Server database which is also hosted in Azure. When I deploy this to an Azure App Service Windows it is twice as fast (calls roughly 400ms instead of 900ms each) as deploying to Azure App Service Linux, despite a higher specification on Linux (B2 instead of B1). They are both configured the same and pointing to the same database. They are also in the same geographic location. What could be the cause?

Please help

Answer (score 0):

`Azure Windows App Service` uses IIS integration.

- Windows App Service has additional options compared to Linux App Service.
  Windows App Service has `Default Documents`(Startup of the Project) and `Path Mappings` option.

[image]

[image]

Whereas in `Azure Linux` we need to mention the Startup command.

[image]

In Azure Windows App Service, as the OS is Windows, latest runtimes are available and keeps the changes up to date.

As mentioned in the [MSDoc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/overview-local-cache)

> `Local cache` option is not available in `Azure Linux App Service`.

Thanks [@Praveen Kumar Sreeram](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/azure-app-service-local-cache/)

> Local cache is a temporary storage where it stores all the content related to Azure App Service.

Local cache forces the instances to pre-load and cache the file system in Advance. Helps to speed up the Application. This might be one of the reasons where `Azure Linux App Service` is slow compared to Windows App Service.

Comment: Thank you for your reply.  I added "WEBSITE_LOCAL_CACHE_OPTION": "Always" to my application settings in Azure and it improved the performance.